# How can I call module function in ASPX markup?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a VB.NET WebForms app and am trying to use inline server tags in the markup to call a function that's located in a module.  No matter what I do, I cannot get intellisense to show the method when I use `<%= %>` or `<%# %>` tags.  Here's my module:

```
Module TestModule

    Function test() As String

        Return String.Empty

    End Function

End Module
```

However, when I convert the module into a class and convert the methods into shared methods, I can do this:

```
Public Class TestClass

    Shared Function test() As String

        Return String.Empty

    End Function

End Class
```

I can place this within my form:

```
<%= MyApp.TestClass.test%>
```

I can use this in control binding:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmWhatever" Text='<%#MyApp.TestClass.test%>' runat="server" />
```

How can I reference module methods from the markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Use this instead:

```
    Public Module TestModule
        Public Function test() As String
          Return String.Empty
        End Function
    End Module
```

'More over you have to use <%@ Import Namespace="Your root namespace" %> on the start of the aspx page

Comment: Confirmed.  Thanks for answer

Comment: What's the value one would use for "Your root namespace" in this case?  Does it come from the Project in VS, or the Module name?  Thanks.

Comment: @Dave it must be from the project in VS